# SFDX FORCE:DATA:TREE:EXPORT Nested __r Relationship Query

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, data-export, nested, cli

I am attempting to export data using the FORCE:DATA:TREE:EXPORT CLI command, using a nested query like the following (for use in our Scratch-Orgs):

```
SELECT ...,(SELECT ... FROM My_Custom_Object__r) FROM Account WHERE ...
```

No matter what I try, I just keep getting errors.  My question is two fold:

1. Can this sort of nested query even be performed across __r relationships where there is no explicit foreign key field (field that would otherwise have an '@Ref' value), using the FORCE:DATA:TREE:EXPORT CLI command?
2. If this is possible, how would an example of the nested query look for a __r relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in Setup at the field on `My_Custom_Object__c` that is a Lookup or Master-Detail to Account. Under Master-Detail Options (or Lookup Options), find the **Child Relationship Name**. This is what gets suffixed with `__r` in a parent-to-child query. In this screenshot, the relationship name is `Business_Lines`:

[image]

So a parent-child query would look like:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Business_Lines__r) FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE 'A%'
```

If the field in your example was created with defaults, then the relationship name is probably My_Custom_Object**s** and the query would be:

```
SELECT ...,(SELECT ... FROM My_Custom_Objects__r) FROM Account WHERE ...
```